# remove the string which has lower number of string

Tags: python

```
 column   1      2           3        4
     A     hot   too hot    school   playground
     B    weather cold     too cold  jacket
     C    rain    water    dirt     rain coat
```

As you can see, there are repeated strings in different columns. Like `hot` and `too hot`. Is there a way where I can keep the string with longer length and delete that specific cell which has the same string?

the output I would want is something like this:

```
 Column   1         2           3          4
    A             too hot    school    playground
    B    weather             too cold   jacket
    B              water        dirt     rain coat

data['repeat'] = data[['1', '2','3','4']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('hot'))
```

This is the code I am working on but this too is only allows me to select a specific string, which is not good if I am working on a large dataset.

Comment: Nice exercise, what to do with “too hot playground” ...

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen I guess delete `hot` and `playground`...

Comment: Is there a reason why the first value of column 2 changed from `too hot` to `hot enough`?

Comment: Check out the Pandas library. There is lots of functionality for doing this type of array manipulation. I would guess something like building a boolean array for the occurrence of the string you want to filter then using that to determine the longest string in each row and masking the other ones out would work.

Comment: To start I would loop the columns, and check each word with the words in the columns too see if they occur in a longer string, rank them and delete the strings that are shorter than the longest.

Comment: playground is the other column, so i would like that to be. only hot is to be removed. @BrunoVermeulen

Comment: sorry its actually too hot only not hot enough. @Tomerikoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents of a solution.

Loop the columns; split the string in the columns into words and loop over the words and check if the words occur in the strings in the other columns; if the case add the index of the column of the shorter string to a set of ids where the string needs to be emptied. Finally empty the string in the columns if the index is in the set.

```
def remove_strings(col_string):
    delete_ids = set()
    for i, s1 in enumerate(col_string):
        words = s1.split()
        for word in words:
            for j, s2 in enumerate(col_string):
                if i != j and word in s2:
                    if len(s1) >= len(s2):
                        delete_ids.add(j)
                    else:
                        delete_ids.add(i)

    for id in delete_ids:
        col_string[id] = ''

    return col_string

col_strings = []
col_strings.append(['hot', 'too hot', 'school', 'playground'])
col_strings.append(['hot chocolate', 'too hot', 'school', 'playground'])
col_strings.append(['weather', 'cold', 'too cold', 'jacket'])
col_strings.append(['rain', 'water', 'dirt', 'rain coat'])

for col_string in col_strings:
    print(f'original: {col_string}')
    print(f'string removed: {remove_strings(col_string)}')
```

```
original: ['hot', 'too hot', 'school', 'playground']
string removed: ['', 'too hot', 'school', 'playground']
original: ['hot chocolate', 'too hot', 'school', 'playground']
string removed: ['hot chocolate', '', 'school', 'playground']
original: ['weather', 'cold', 'too cold', 'jacket']
string removed: ['weather', '', 'too cold', 'jacket']
original: ['rain', 'water', 'dirt', 'rain coat']
string removed: ['', 'water', 'dirt', 'rain coat']
```

Comment: Thank you so much this actually worked perfectly for me.

Comment: You are welcome, appreciate if you can click answered for my kudos. Thanks.